# how to make sure when I see the code on the web console is not messy

Tags: javascript

I was given a web example provided by my mentor. I press Ctrl + Shift + i so I can see the code for reference. But this is what I see:

[image: click the link]

Comment: Click the bracket icon in the bottom left of the picture to format the code

Comment: Use the non-minified version of jQuery to get it formatted nicely and meaningful variable names.

Comment: Here's the uncompressed version: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js (that's the most current one, not the severely outdated 1.x version though) However I don't think your mentor gave you jQuery in order to analyze it; you're probably supposed to learn how to use it I guess? In that case I'd start here: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/

Comment: The picture seems to be of the Google Chrome browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you've sent includes a file named Jquery.min.js, First off Jquery is a library which provides helpful functions for web development, secondly as the name suggests that it is minified so that the file consumes as less space as possible so as to make the page load faster.

Your mentor has probably used this library in the webpage and used the functions provided by the library, What you would actually want to see is your own Javascript code, For that, you can CTRL+P on the sources section and search your Javascript file name, or otherwise if it's written on the webpage itself, then go ahead and search the webpage itself and see the code there.

Or otherwise if you want to see the formatted code of the Jquery itself then as Barmar has suggested, use the non-minfied version of the Library itself.